# $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\sum_{n\leq x} (\log n)^k/n - \int_1^x (\log t)^k/t\right) = \text{?}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

It is easy to see (by Euler-Maclaurin, say, or just by thinking of a graph) that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{(\log n)^k}{n} = \int_1^x \frac{(\log t)^k}{t} + C + O\left(\frac{(\log x)^k}{x}\right).$$
(Here of course $\int_1^x (\log t)^k/t = (\log x)^{k+1}/(k+1)$.) If $k=0$, then $C$ is Euler's constant $\gamma$.

Is there a closed expression for $C$ in general, for $k$ a positive integer? Here "closed expression" is understood to be something that can involve values of higher derivatives of $\zeta$, say.

(No expression with infinite sums, though, unless it is just one infinite sum and it looks nice! It is clear a priori that one can express $C$ as a rapidly convergent sum of some expression involving values  of $\zeta$ -- lots of series can be expressed in that way.)

Comment: it equals to $(-1)^k(\frac{\partial}{\partial s})^k (\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1})$ evaluated at point 1, as follows from the representation $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} t^{-s}dt)$.

Comment: Oops. I am a big boobie.

Comment: And of course these are just the coefficients of the Laurent expansion at $s=1$, which have a name (Stieltjes constants). I am a very big boobie.

Comment: Upto some factorials, I guess

Comment: Sure - I mean that $\zeta(s) = 1/(s-1) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty ((-1)^k \gamma_k/k!) (s-1)^k$, where $k$ is the limit in the question.